# Good use of p:dataExporter for CSV/PDF export

Tags: csv, jsf, pdf, jsf-2, primefaces

Trying to add 3 export buttons for a `dataTable` (CSV / XLS / PDF) using `DataExporter`, I'm facing some issues I think due to the framework:

1. CSV export wrong encoding french accents (é -> Ã© ...)
2. CSV export can't be used with repeat option (Exception "Not supported yet")
3. PDF export kicks all french accents

My question is, Do I need to use a CustomExporter in order to fix these problems ? If so, what's the good way ? I have problems to find some piece of information and tutorials, and am pretty new to JSF/PF.

---

**Update**: Encoding accents is fixed with option `encoding="ISO-8859-1"` in my dataExporter. The second issue is fixed by using not `repeat` option but `pageOnly="false"` option.